# Is the DataLoader object an iterable object?

Tags: python, pytorch

This is the code

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import numpy as np
import math

# creating a custom class for our dataset, which inherits from Dataset.
class WineDataset(Dataset):

    # this function is used for data loading
    def __init__(self):
      # data loading
      xy = np.loadtxt('./wine.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=np.float32, skiprows=1)
      self.x = torch.from_numpy(xy[:, 1:])  # the first column is the output label
      self.y = torch.from_numpy(xy[:, [0]]) # n_samples, 1
      self.n_samples = xy.shape[0]

    # this function allows indexing in our dataset
    def __getitem__(self, index):
      return self.x[index], self.y[index] # the function returns a tuple.

    # this allows us to call len on our dataset.
    def __len__(self):
      return self.n_samples

dataset = WineDataset()
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=dataset, batch_size=4, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

dataiter = iter(dataloader)
data = next(dataiter)
features, labels = data
print(features, labels)
```

My question is that since, we can already call the enumerate method directly on the dataloader, does it mean that the dataloader object is an iterable ?
If this is true, then calling iter(dataloader) would be the same as creating an iterator object from an iterator object ?

I'm a bit confused about this please help me out.

I need to know what the enumerate method is doing behind the scenes when dataloader is passed as an argument. Also need to know what iter(dataloader) is doing.

Comment: Can't  you print the value of `dataiter` to find out what kind if iterator it is?

Comment: iterator =/= iterable. List is iterable, but not an iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterable is something which implements `__iter__` method. Iterator is something which implements `__next__` method. Both `iter()` and `enumerate()` call the `__iter___` method of the class. for example

```
class A: # this is an iterable
    def __iter__(self):
        print ('iter called at A')
        return B()
    
class B: # this is an iterator
    def __next__(self):
        print( 'next called at B')
        return 1
```

Note, any object of class `B` is an iterator because it implements `__next__` but its not an iterable becuase it doesn't have `__iter__` method. Similarly, any object of class `A` is an iterable but not an iterator.

Run it,

```
a = A()
```

create an iterator

```
b = iter(a)
print(f'{type(b)=}')
```

```
"""
iter called at A
type(b)=<class '__main__.B'>
"""
```

calling `next()` on iterator `b`

```
next(b)
```

```
"""
next called at B
1
"""
```

can't call `next()` on iterable `a`

```
next(a)
```

```
"""
TypeError: 'A' object is not an iterator
"""
```

We can do a `for` loop on `a`

```
for i in a:
    print(i)
    break
```

```
"""
iter called at A
next called at B
1
"""
```

Can't do a `for` loop on `b`

```
for i in b:
    print(i)
    break
```

```
"""
TypeError: 'B' object is not iterable
"""
```

Now, call `enumerate`

```
c = enumerate(a)
print(f'{type(c)=}')
```

```
"""
iter called at A
type(c)=<class 'enumerate'>
"""
```

Can do a `for` loop on c as well as call `next()`

```
next(c)
```

```
"""
next called at B
(0, 1)
"""
```

```
for i in c:
    print(i)
    break
```

```
"""
next called at B
(1, 1)
"""
```

So the `enumerate` class is both an iterator and an iterable because it has both `__iter__` and `__next__` methods. You can check this by calling `dir(c)`.

When we call `enumerate` on a `Dataloader`, its `__iter__` method is called. Looking at the signature of `__iter__` function in pytorch source code:

```
class DataLoader(Generic[T_co]):
.
.
    def __iter__(self) -> '_BaseDataLoaderIter':
```

This `_BaseDataLoaderIter` class implements both `__iter__` and `__next__`, so its both an iterable and an iterator.

```
class _BaseDataLoaderIter(object):
.
.
    def __iter__(self) -> '_BaseDataLoaderIter':
        return self

    def __next__(self) -> Any:
    .
    .
        return data
```

So you can call both `enumerate()` and `iter()` on `Dataloader` and can even do `for` loops. You can check source code in your python directly somewhere at
`..\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py`

Comment: this cleared all my doubts. 1 small issue - at the start of the answer I think you interchanged iterable and iterator. It should've been - an iterable implements the __iter__ method and an iterator implements the __next__ method.